# Hibernate - Could not load requested class : org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mariadb

So my issues is pretty basic. I'm just running a simple hibernate web application that sends a new entry to my SQL MariaDB. When I run the application I get an error message saying the requested class could not be loaded. What doesn't make sense is I have the .jar files in my library and my other test file runs fine. For this project I'm using Intellij IDEA.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker</property>
    <property name="connection.username">hbstudent</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect</property>

    <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Set the current session context -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

</session-factory>
```

**CreateStudentDemo**

```
import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class CreateStudentDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create session factory
    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                             .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                             .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                             .buildSessionFactory();
    // create session
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    try {
        // create a student object
        System.out.println("Creating new student object...");
        Student tempStudent = new Student(
                              "Paul", "Wall", "paul@luv2code.com");

        // start a transaction
        session.beginTransaction();

        // save the student object
        System.out.println("Saving the student...");
        session.save(tempStudent);

        // commit transaction
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
    finally {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm thinking the issue lies with the hibernate.xml file. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **com**.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Could not load requested class : **org**.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Documentation I was reading said it was com. Fixed my issue. THANK YOU.